# GROUP BY ROLLUP gives labels as Null in SOQL Query

Tags: soql, group-by-rollup

I am using `GROUP BY ROLLUP` in query to get totals & subtotals of aggregate columns.But while the result of total & subtotals are displayed i am getting their labels as Null instead of Total & Sub total.
Here is the query i am using to populate below table.

I am getting Total in First row but its labeled as Null and then each subtotal after each Breakdown but again the 'Sub Total' is labeled as again Null.

I am using GROUP BY Rollup on this 2 fields.

```
SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name
```

**How can i get label as TOTAL & SUB-TOTAL? I am looking for TOTAL & Sub total of rows**

```
[SELECT SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ownerName,SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c accountGeo ,SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c) recurringAmount,
                                      SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_One_Time_Amount_rollup__c) oneTimeAmount,COUNT(OrderNumber) ordNo FROM Order where (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c >=:currentFQStartDate) AND (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c <=:currentFQEndDate)
                                      GROUP BY ROLLUP(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) ORDER BY SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c ASC,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ]
```

[image: Table data]

**EDIT - Added the Code where I am building the HTML body.**

**EDIT2 - Changed the Code as mentioned in the answer given.**
[image: EDITED After adding the code mentioned in the Answer below]

```
    htmlBody = '<table border="1"  class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption><b>Report for Orders Closed Current Quarter</b></caption><tr><th></th><th>$New Recurring Amount</th><th>$New OneTime Amount</th><th>No.of Deals</th></tr>';
for(AggregateResult clsOrd : [SELECT SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ownerName,SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c accountGeo ,GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) grpOwnerName,                         
                              GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c) grpAccountGeo,SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c) recurringAmount,
                              SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_One_Time_Amount_rollup__c) oneTimeAmount,COUNT(OrderNumber) ordNo 
                              FROM Order 
                              where (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c >=:currentFQStartDate) AND 
                              (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c <=:currentFQEndDate) AND SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c!= null
                              GROUP BY 
                              ROLLUP(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) 
                              ORDER BY SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c ASC,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ]){
                                  
                                  Boolean isSubTotalByGeo = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                                      ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAccountGeo')) == 0;
                                  // Detect  grandtotal (all geos)
                                  Boolean isGrandTotal = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                                      ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAccountGeo')) == 1;
                                  String column1Val;
                                  if (isGrandTotal) {
                                      column1Val = 'GRAND TOTAL';
                                  }
                                  else if (isSubTotalByGeo) {
                                      column1Val = 'SUB TOTAL';
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      column1Val = (String) clsOrd.get('ownerName');
                                  }
                                  system.debug('column1Val '+column1Val);
                                  newRecurringAmt = Double.valueOf(clsOrd.get('recurringAmount'));
                                  newOneTimeAmt = Double.valueOf(clsOrd.get('oneTimeAmount'));
                                  if(accountGeo!='' && accountGeo!= clsOrd.get('accountGeo')){
                                      system.debug('newRecurringSubTotal '+newRecurringSubTotal);
                                      newRecurringSubTotal = 0;
                                      newOneTimeSubTotal = 0;
                                      orderSubTotal = 0;
                                  }
                                  
                                  if(accountGeo!= clsOrd.get('accountGeo')){
                                      htmlBody += ' <thead><tr class="slds-line-height_reset"><th class="" scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title= '+clsOrd.get('accountGeo')+' Breakdown>'+clsOrd.get('accountGeo')+' Breakdown</div></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>';
                                  }
                                  htmlBody += '<tr class="slds-hint-parent"><td>' +clsOrd.get('ownerName') + '</td>';
                                  htmlBody += '<td>' +newRecurringAmt.format() + '</td><td>'+newOneTimeAmt.format() + '</td>';
                                  htmlBody += '<td>' + clsOrd.get('ordNo') + '</td></tr><br/>';
                                  accountGeo = String.valueOf(clsOrd.get('accountGeo'));
                                  
                              }
```

SO I am directly using this `htmlBody` in `EmaiService` to send the email.

```
EmailService service = new EmailService(email);
service.body = 'Dear'+' '+orderOwnerName+','+ '<br/><br/>Here is Report'+' '+reportName+' '+'Containing Closed Orders.<br/><br/>'+emailBody;
service.body += '<br/><br/>Regards,<br/>Salesforce Admin Team.'; 
service.isHtml = true;
service.toAddresses = new List<string>();
```

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm and use Apex to insert the desired labels for subtotals

Comment: But how can i add that to field which is already aggregated. SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c) like this is giving syntax error SUM(GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c))

Comment: presumably you are using a wrapper (inner) class to make available the aggregate data to the VF? page. So, when you populate the wrapper object, test for the presence of a subtotal, grand total row and coerce in your own labels

Comment: I am not using any wrapper. I wrote a method which returns the html body prepared using that query and then I am using that htmlBody in EmailService to send the table. And i am sending email with table shown not displaying in VF. So here with GROUP BY ROLLUP i think the total & sub total is getting populated but how can i determine it here.? EDITED my question to add more code & details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added comments as required.

```
    htmlBody = '<table border="1"  class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption><b>Report for Orders Closed Current Quarter</b></caption><tr><th></th><th>$New Recurring Amount</th><th>$New OneTime Amount</th><th>No.of Deals</th></tr>';
    for(AggregateResult clsOrd : [SELECT SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ownerName,SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c accountGeo ,GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) grpOwnerName,                         
                                  GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c) grpAccountGeo,SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c) recurringAmount,
                                  SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_One_Time_Amount_rollup__c) oneTimeAmount,COUNT(OrderNumber) ordNo 
                                  FROM Order 
                                  where (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c >=:currentFQStartDate) AND 
                                  (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c <=:currentFQEndDate) AND SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c!= null
                                  GROUP BY 
                                  ROLLUP(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) 
                                  ORDER BY SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c ASC,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ]){
                                      
                                      Boolean isSubTotalByGeo = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                                          ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAccountGeo')) == 0;
                                      // Detect  grandtotal (all geos)
                                      Boolean isGrandTotal = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                                          ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAccountGeo')) == 1;
                                      String column1Val;
                                      if (isGrandTotal) {
                                          column1Val = 'GRAND TOTAL';
                                      }
                                      else if (isSubTotalByGeo) {
                                          column1Val = 'SUB TOTAL';
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          column1Val = (String) clsOrd.get('ownerName');
                                      }
                                      system.debug('column1Val '+column1Val);
                                      newRecurringAmt = Double.valueOf(clsOrd.get('recurringAmount'));
                                      newOneTimeAmt = Double.valueOf(clsOrd.get('oneTimeAmount'));
                                      if(accountGeo!='' && accountGeo!= clsOrd.get('accountGeo')){
                                          system.debug('newRecurringSubTotal '+newRecurringSubTotal);
                                          newRecurringSubTotal = 0;
                                          newOneTimeSubTotal = 0;
                                          orderSubTotal = 0;
                                      }
                                     

> //Null check condition for First row not to appear.

                                      if(accountGeo!= clsOrd.get('accountGeo') && clsOrd.get('accountGeo')!= null){
                                          htmlBody += ' <thead><tr class="slds-line-height_reset"><th class="" scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title= '+clsOrd.get('accountGeo')+' Breakdown>'+clsOrd.get('accountGeo')+' Breakdown</div></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>';
                                      }

> //Here is the Main part where I had to add the column1Val for which I
> was struggling.

                                      htmlBody += '<tr class="slds-hint-parent"><td>' +column1Val + '</td>';
                                      htmlBody += '<td>' +newRecurringAmt.format() + '</td><td>'+newOneTimeAmt.format() + '</td>';
                                      htmlBody += '<td>' + clsOrd.get('ordNo') + '</td></tr><br/>';
                                      accountGeo = String.valueOf(clsOrd.get('accountGeo'));
                                      
                                  }
```

[image: Reports Using Aggregate result]

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your Aggregate query to look like this:

```
for(AggregateResult clsOrd : 
     [SELECT 
            SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ownerName,
            SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c accountGeo,
            GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) grpOwnerName,                         
            GROUPING(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c) grpAccountGeo ,                                    
            SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_Recurring_Amount_formula__c) recurringAmount,                                    
            SUM(SBQQ__Quote__r.New_One_Time_Amount_rollup__c) oneTimeAmount,
            COUNT(OrderNumber) ordNo 
      FROM Order 
      WHERE (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c >=:currentFQStartDate) AND 
            (Opportunity_Closed_Date__c <=:currentFQEndDate)
      GROUP BY 
            ROLLUP(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name) 
      ORDER BY SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Geo__c ASC,SBQQ__Quote__r.Owner.Name ]){

  // Detect subtotal by Geo
  Boolean isSubTotalByGeo = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                            ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAcccountGeo')) == 0;
  // Detect  grandtotal (all geos)
  Boolean isGrandTotal = ((Integer)clsOrd.get('grpOwnerName')) == 1 &&
                         ((Integer) clsord.get('grpAcccountGeo')) == 1; 

 // Then use these Booleans to decide how to populate the first column of your HTML table
 String column1Val;
 if (isGrandTotal) {column1Val = 'GRAND TOTAL';}
 else if (isSubTotalByGeo) {column1Val = 'ALL OWNERS';}
 else {column1Val = (String) clsOrd.get('ownerName');}

 // construct HTML here ...
}
```

[Documentation reference: Using GROUPING(fieldName) to Identify Subtotals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm)

Some asides:

1. I find that using ALL CAPS for SOQL aliases improves readability
2. Nicely formatting complex (or lengthy SOQL improves readability
3. If ever there was a use case for a VF email template that used a VF component+controller, this would be it. You decouple the the formatting of the email to the markup in the VF component and you then use the component controller to query and build a data structure of rows that are made available via a getter to an `apex:dataTable` VF component. All the styling is done in the VF markup and the controller only needs to worry about data and data structure.  In other words, *Separation of Concerns*

Comment: Thanks for the response. But by just changing the Aggregate query null values in table are not getting change.

Comment: I am not  understanding how can i replace that null values with Total & subtotal. The thing is i am not understanding from where this null values(ROWS) are getting populated.

Comment: the example in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm was pretty self explanatory. Each row coming back from the Aggregate query is either a detail row, a subtotal row, or a grand total row and the `Grouping(xx)` fields in the result row tells you this

Comment: Yes but even the table in this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm is having Null Labels to Grand total rows right?

Comment: In fact with the given solution above it is still giving me same table with Null column labels.

Comment: Please see the EDIT2 part.

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED. Adding the edits in the Answer.